# Piecewise linear regression in R (segmented.lm)

Tags: r, regression, piecewise

I appreciate any help to make *segmented.lm* (or any other function) find the obvious breakpoints in this example:

```
data = list(x=c(50,60,70,80,90) , y= c(703.786,705.857,708.153,711.056,709.257))
plot(data, type='b')
require(segmented)
model.lm = segmented(lm(y~x,data = data),seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA)
```

It returns with the following error:

Error in solve.default(crossprod(x1), crossprod(x1, y1)) :
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.51417e-20

If I change K:

```
model.lm = segmented(lm(y~x,data = data),seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K=1))
```

I get another error:

> Error in segmented.lm(lm(y ~ x, data = data), seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K = 1)) :
> only 1 datum in an interval: breakpoint(s) at the boundary or too close each other

Comment: I hope that's just a sample data set because that's really far too few observations to try to estimate something like that. The problem when you don't specify K is that the default value is 10. Since you have fewer than observations, this default doesn't make sense and you can't differentiate between models. The problem with K=1 is that it's trying the break at just after 80 which leaves only one point in that second group making it impossible to calculate a slope. But you really need a much larger input data set.

Comment: Like @MrFlick said, you have too few observations here.  Try: `data = data.frame(x=c(50,60,70,80,90,100,110) , y= c(703.786,705.857,708.153,711.056,709.257, 707.4, 705.6))`. Then this will work:  `model.lm = segmented(lm(y~x,data = data),seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K=1))
`

Comment: Thank you MrFlick and Frank.
I will use a larger dataset eventually. But for this sample set, I could manage to get a model with:

library("SiZer")
model.pwl = piecewise.linear(x = data$x, y = data$y,  middle = 1, CI = FALSE, bootstrap.samples = 1000, sig.level = 0.05)
plot(model.pwl)

Answer (score 0):

A nice objective method to determine the break point is described in Crawley (2007: 427).

First, define a vector `breaks` for a range of potential break points:

```
breaks <- data$x[data$x >= 70 & data$x <= 90]
```

Then run a `for` loop for piecewise regressions for all potential break points and yank out the minimal residual standard error (`mse`) for each model from the `summary` output:

```
mse <- numeric(length(breaks))
for(i in 1:length(breaks)){
  piecewise <- lm(data$y ~ data$y*(data$x < breaks[i]) + data$y*(data$x >= breaks[i]))
  mse[i] <- summary(piecewise)[6]
}
mse <- as.numeric(mse)
```

Finally, identify the break point with the least `mse`:

```
breaks[which(mse==min(mse))]
```

Hope this helps.